# Standard deviation of 3D matrix

Tags: r, std

I want to compute the standard deviation of a 3D matrix in Matlab. 
The matrix is called quiz 1 and its' dimensions are `7x13x19`. 
I attempted the following commands but got different values:

```
Quiz1 = reshape(quiz1, 1, 1729);
STD = std(Quiz1)
Or
S = std(std(std(quiz1)))
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10896-standard-deviation-of-a-3d-matrix?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) MATLAB answer.

Answer (score 0):

R matrices and arrays are just vectors with dimension attributes if you use mean or sd on them you will get results from the total ensemble of cell values. If that's not what you want, then you need to clarify:

```
sd( matrix(1:9,3) )
[1] 2.738613
sd( array(1:27, c(3,3,3) ) )
[1] 7.937254
```

If this was really a Matlab question, then please correct the tagging.